# Program works, but TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable is received. Why?

Tags: python, string, slice, typeerror

This program checks to see if a string is a palindrome then returns true if it is. It works fine when I run it in the Python IDLE. But is not accepted on the online testing site, returning this error: "**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**"

```
string="racecar"
def is_palindrome(string):
        if string == string[::-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Why is this? To my knowledge I'm not working with int's.

Comment: The testing site is probably using non strings as input

Comment: This error indicates that the "string" variable passed to the method is an integer and not a string (assuming the exception raised at this point)

Comment: Does the testing site always use "racecar" as the input, or can it make up its own inputs?

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist. Thanks your solution was the ticket it worked beautifully. Submit it as an answer and ill upvote!

Comment: @mattyb Comment converted to answer

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist im not popular enough to upvote apparently. Sorry for the false hope, I accepted it as the correct answer tho thanks again

Comment: @mattyb Np. I don't live and die by upvotes. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously want your function to only operate on strings, and unless you're using a quite new version of Python supporting type hints, you can't really tell Python that. So just cast to string right off the bat. Almost anything can be cast to a string and then your function will work no matter what it is passed, or at least throw a decent error.

```
def is_palindrome(string):
        string = str(string)    # add this line
        if string == string[::-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```